# Stuck on the diagnosis part of my android application

Tags: java, android

I need an advise on the best approach to complete this task in my android app:

I am working on an android app and got stuck on how to calculate the diagnosis of the patient.

1. The user (doctor) will perform physical tests on the patient
2. The user records the value of each physical test <= this data is stored in a shared pref object
   i.e- when the user performs an empty can test (physical test), the user will record if the test is positive (1) or negative (0) <= Boolean value (for simplicity, I am using only 4 tests)
3. The application is supposed to compare the patient findings to the conditions that I want to just hard code in my app (for simplicity, I am using only 8 conditions to compare) then display the condition that the patient would most likely have

--> I am storing the physical test, performed on the patient, results in a shared preference object but do not know how to go from there to come up with the diagnosis (I am looking for a simple approach to make this work)

*** I saved the values from my shared preference object into one dimensional array as below:

```
// User SharedPreferences to save the value per special id
        SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("STData", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        Map<String, String> map = (Map<String, String>) sharedPref.getAll();
        int[] PTFindings = new int[map.size()];
        int index = 0;

        if(!map.isEmpty()){
            Iterator<Map.Entry<String, String>> iterator = map.entrySet().iterator();
            while(iterator.hasNext()){
                Map.Entry entry = (Map.Entry)iterator.next();
                PTFindings[index] = (int) entry.getValue();

            }
        }
```

**** How should I hard code few conditions to proceed? -> assuming the results of the physical tests of those conditions (positive (1) or negative (0)) do not change

*** I need to compare their values to the one I saved from shared preference then display the most likely diagnosis

Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

As far as I could understando from your question, you just need a cascading condition.

```
if(boolean1){
   if(boolean2){
      //something boolean2 related
   } else {
      if(boolean3){
         etc...
      }
   }
} else {
   //something boolean1 related
}
```